# Drag and drop a link on the desktop to create a shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, web, desktop-integration

My client asked me a interesting thing today.

Drag and drop a link in the browser on the desktop to create a shortcut to the linked webpage.

We have a web-application and it could be very good to enable the user to directly connect their application.

Do you have any idea of how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this how it actually works with most browsers in Windows? I've just tried in Firefox and IE, and both gave me a shortcut direct to the page on the desktop. Or am I missing something in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Windows as-is.  If you're talking about some sort of javascript link or button I"m afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging any link to the desktop should work, but you could extend it by creating a special link (perhaps per screen) that will let the user return to the exact application state.
Obviously you would have to add any state-preserving info into the links URL. You might also have to update the web application to restore the state based on that info.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously you would have to add any state-preserving info into the links URL.

A further suggestion: put the state in the *anchor* of the URL, like so:

http://mycompany.com/myapplication#mystatevariable=xyz

That way, the browser doesn't reload the whole application.  Of course, you'll have to monitor the URL and process the anchor in Javascript.